# angular2-webpack-starter how to add NodeJS server to project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack

I cloned an angular2-webpack-starter project and it works well; now I want to add a separate NodeJS server to this project(I need to mock some data with NodeJS for back-end), but don't know how and where to start, can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved, just need to config proxy of devServer in config/webpack.dev.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry:{...},
  ...
  devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8086, //frontend port
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true,
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: 100
        },
        outputPath: '/',
        proxy: {
            '/api/*': { //backend url prefix, some thing like '/api/users/:userId'
                target: 'http://localhost:3000', // backend host and port
                secure: false
            }
        }
    }
};
```